# 403 responses are OK?

Tags: http, response

In HTTP, I know a standard 200 response has "OK" on the end. But I can't seem to find if other codes such as 403 need the OK.

For example (from Wikipedia):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 23 May 2005 22:38:34 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.3.7 (Unix) (Red-Hat/Linux)
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
Etag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 131
Connection: close

<html>
<head>
  <title>An Example Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hello World, this is a very simple HTML document.
</body>
</html>
```

So in a 403 response would it start with:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 OK
```

Or:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN
```

Or just:

```
HTTP/1.1 403
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely it will start with

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

Basically, the answer to your question is “403 responses are not OK, but you can write whatever you want there.”

The format of this line is defined as:

```
Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF
```

Here is what the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1) says:

> The `Reason-Phrase` is intended to give a short textual description of the `Status-Code`. The `Status-Code` is intended for use by automata and the **`Reason-Phrase`** is intended for the **human** user. *The client is not required to examine or display the `Reason-Phrase`*.

> The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations -- they **MAY** be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol.

But there is normally no reason to do this (no reason to replace reason ;).

Also the list of status codes with their recommended reasons is [here](http://iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xml).

Comment: No, the list of status codes is here: <http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xml>

Comment: @JulianReschke Wow, I never heard that RFC on upgrading to TLS established IANA registry for status code. Thanks for the info, that's great!

Comment: I should say that the last edit to my answer is heavily based on an edit suggested by [Andre D](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2272778/andre-d), but unfortunatelly when I noticed the edit it was already rejected by others.

Answer (score -3):

A 403 response will never be followed by OK.

Comment: Well, that's not exactly true, because you can write your own web server sending whatever you want… And it will work since no client is checking the status string, since there is a status code present.

Comment: True, good point. I guess I wasn't thinking of it in that context. Thanks.

Comment: Not true.  Google drive API return 403 OK on rate limited responses.

Comment: AWS buckets can sometimes return a 403 OK.